# Php autoincrement variable

Tags: php, yii

Hola tengo un problema cuando hago el autoincrement, en el primero que es 0 no tendria que salir, peor si hay mas de uno tendria que salir la incremntacion a partir de 1. Luego se tendria que guardar. Pero no me funciona. Me pueden ayudar? Gracias!

```
        if(isset($_POST['Image'])){
        foreach($images_array as $key =>$row){
            if($key = 0){
                $name = $_POST['Product']['product_Name'];
                $filename = generateSeoURL($name);
            }else{
            $i = 1;
            foreach($images_array as $row){
                $name = $_POST['Product']['product_Name'] . '-' . $i++;
                $filename = generateSeoURL($name);
            }
            //$filename = generateSeoURL($_POST['Product']['product_Name']);
            Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->update('image', array(
                'image_AdName' => $filename,
                'image_AdPath' => 'test path',
            ),  'image_Id=:image_Id', array(':image_Id'=>$images_array[$key]['image_id']));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien el problema, pero si es por que el primero te sale 0 en lugar de 1 pon `++$i;` en lugar de `$i++;`

Comment: imposible que el primero le salga 0 si puso $i = 1 antes de entrar. yo tampoco entiendo bien el problema

Answer (score 1):

Tu código esta mal

> if($key = 0)

Estas haciendo una asignación por tanto siempre $key será CERO (0)